# How to compute median without storing all the values?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, median

I have a source of data that continuously gives me measurement results. At some point I compute the mean. Luckily to this end, I don't need to store all the values, I only store the sum and the number of results, so I can divide one by the other. It is important because of efficiency reason, as I have loads of such sources operating concurrently.

The requirement has just changed and I was asked for the median instead of the mean. In order to compute the median, one needs all the values from the data set, which in my case would exhaust computer memory, thus I am thinking of an improvement. The idea I have is storing histograms and approximating medians from them. Nevertheless, creating a histogram object for each data source (which I have millions) might not pay back for sources that produce very few values.

In short, I'd appreciate any comments related to median, quartiles and median absolute deviation computations optimization.

Comment: This is a pretty standard coding problem As you have mentioned about computer programming I know a solution using Heaps and You will not need to sort your entries out ! If You want I can answer it out ! But there is no solution without storing values as far as I know

Comment: I honestly don't think that there is an efficient solution.

Comment: What you are looking for is an "online" algorithm to compute the median in constant space, and I don't think an exact one exists. There are approximate algorithms, and if you know the kind of values you are expecting (for instance if the inputs are a finite set of integers) you could get a good answer by counting occurrences. As for your histogram idea, you could always use a cheap solution (like keeping a short list of values, and using an O(n) median-finding algorithm when required) and then switch to a histogram once there is enough data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Could you please elaborate on the "heap" solution? Or provide a link to appropriate reading? I never heard of that and the histogram was just an idea (don't know if it is standard or used).

Comment: If you can imagine storing a histogram, why not just compute median while you have full dataset in memory and then store the median. More generally, may be better to store five number summary: min, Q1, median Q3, max (Q's are quartiles) instead of just median. Cheaper than storing histogram, anyway.

Comment: @BruceET I think what is cheaper depends on the histogram binning and the size of the dataset. You can imagine situations when histogram comes much cheaper.